# SVN, exclamation and question marks on file after checkout

Tags: svn

I have just checked svn repository out and got this in `svn st` output:

```
?       trunk/doc/PaymentSystems/Протокол_взаимодействия.doc
!       trunk/doc/PaymentSystems/Протокол_взаимодействия.doc
```

I don't need this file personally, but it prevents me from merging:

```
svn: E195016: Merge tracking not allowed with missing subtrees; try restoring these items first:
trunk/doc/PaymentSystems/Протокол_взаимодействия.doc
```

I tried `svn revert` and `svn cleanup`, deleting and checking file out, nothing helped. There might be some problem with the encoding (filename is in cyrillics), I presume, but don't know how to fix the issue. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: FYI, you can find out what status icons mean (apart from documentation itself) if you run `svn help status`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Ok, thanks, but how can I fix this? Just after `checkout` the file is stated as new(?) and missing(!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I initially thought the problem is due to filename. Some "strange" names like `Протокол_взаимодействия.doc` (often these include hieroglyphs or diacritic letters, `й` in this case) would cause this kind of problem on some filesystems, at least *HFS+* like MacOS has. Mac here use *decomposed* handling of such characters, unlike Linux/Windows, storing two separate symbols (upper and lower parts of the letter `й` in my case). Therefore svn thinks that we either added a new file and deleted one simultaneously. Long story short, the fix:

- check the current version of svn and delete it. I had installed mine with `brew`, so I uninstalled those with `brew uninstall svn`.
- install svn from this repo: https://github.com/tholu/homebrew-tap , it has the patch for correct utf paths.
- link the version with `brew link subversion18`.
- check the version with `svn --version`, would look like:

`svn, version 1.8.16
(r1740329) compiled Dec 21 2016, 16:31:22 on x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0`